# java checkbox is checked? then loop

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

i have checkbox and i want

1. If checkbox is checked : make loop every 10 Minutes
2. And on uncheck : go out from loop

Below is event of checkbox :-

```
final JCheckBox rfh = new JCheckBox("Auto Refresh");
toolbar.add(rfh);
toolbar.setAlignmentX(0);
rfh.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            while ( rfh.isSelected() ) {
                if (rfh.isSelected()) {
                   // ((JCheckBox)evt.getSource()).isSelected()
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(toolbar,"thank you for using java");
                   Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(toolbar,"not selected");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: You might want to tell us, what you mean by 'make loop'. Also check out 'javax.swing.Timer'

Comment: @maneesh i am changed question

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a look at:

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)
- [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Basically, Swing is a single threaded environment, so don't try and use a loop and `Thread.sleep` within the `ActionPerformed` method.

The two easiest solutions would either be...

### Use a Swing `Timer`

A Swing `Timer` will allow you to setup a regular scheduled call back.  This callback will be executed within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, making it great for updating the UI from.

It can easily be started and stopped.

The draw back is, it is notified within the context of the EDT, which makes it a poor choice for making calls to the database, which could cause the program to "stutter" every time it is called...

### or Use a `SwingWorker`

A `SwingWorker` provides the means to perform work in the background, but provides functionality that makes it easy to make updates to the UI.

Basically, you would need to setup a loop of some kind (within the workers `doInBackground` method) and use `Thread.sleep` to wait for a prescribed period of time.  Once `Thread.sleep` returns, you would make your call to the database, built a your data model and pass it to the `publish` method.

Within the `process` method, which is called within the context of the EDT, you would process these results and update your table model accordingly...

The drawback with this is you will need to devise the means by which the worker can be stopped (or turned off) and, if you're so inclined, restarted...

Comment: Check the links, there are examples there.  Search SO for `[java] [swing] timer`...I've post a few hundred examples myself